# USB Wi-Fi Adpt Issue with Ubuntu Studio 20.04. Laptop using weak 300kb signal from built-in wifi ant

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, internet, ubuntu-studio

I'm happy to unhook the antenna inside the machine if that's what it takes, but I'm having difficulty understanding how to get Ubuntu Studio 20.04 to recognize my Belkin USB Wi-Fi adpt.

It's weird because it totally saw it in trial mode, even giving me the option at the click of my mouse to choose between my laptop antenna and the Belkin. It saw it right away, even blinking the indicator light before I configured it. 
..Yet, after the hard-disk install, it's not even blinking. No menu option, nothing..not even a sign that it's using my internal like it did in trial mode (showing me the names of the ants and all).

I'm pretty sad about this, as it seems to be an issue across quite a few linux distros. So far the only OS capable of easily turning off my laptops ant in fav of my USB Wi-Fi adpt is win8.1, which I'd rather not be using.

So what's the deal here? I'm thinking it's simple and I just can't see it.  So far I'm loving this distro, just wish it to act like it did in trial mode.

Cheers and thanks for reading,
Christopher

Comment: *UPDATE*: Ubuntu Studio 20.04 now sees my Belkin USB Wi-Fi, ...BUT I'm not certain it's actually using it. Even after clicking on the off option for my laptop's internal ant, and switching the USB to be the only option, it still has issues. As if it's trying to cycle back to the internal. I can see it using the Belkin, but not all the time. Lots of dropped connections and odd slow downs. Thinking this is a Terminal type job..but I don't know.

Comment: UPDATE 2: Ubuntu not only has problems using my Belkin, but seems to slow down the entire system just to use it. Firefox loading tabs slowly and freezing up. I don't mind too much getting a different one, but the one I have works just fine outside of Ubuntu.